# php array parent array position

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to get the the current position of an array from within a nested array ?

I have a php script that has a for loop which cycles through an array, with in this is an nested loop which cycle through a sub array. 
I can use pos() to get the position of the child array, is there anyway of getting the current position of the parent array.

I am sure there must be a way to do this, or is the best way to just create a counter?

thanks in advance

.k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a for loop, you already have a counter. In this example, it's $i :

```
for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) ...
```

If you're actually using a foreach loop, use the syntax that gives you the key:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) ...
```

Comment: Hey Scott, 

It is a foreach loop, your suggestion done the job!  
  
Thanks .k

Answer (score 0):

A PHP variable has no information from where it is referenced - due to references and copy-on-write there might be even more things (global/local variables, array elements, properties, ...) pointing to a single variables.

If you have a reference to the "parent" element you can use pos() on that, if not you have to handle this yourself.